# AVG LinkScanner is blocking this question

Tags: support, specific-question, virus

My antivirus AVG LinkScanner is preventing me to open [Weird Javascript in Template. Is this a hacking attempt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019353/weird-javascript-in-template-is-this-a-hacking-attempt)

[image]

I am sure it wasn't blocked just because certain keywords, as in the past I have read thousands of hacking related articles and never had this problem.

I think it is a false-positive and nobody is in real danger, but I feel like it is my duty to inform about this anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is SO's problem - isn't this an issue with AVG? How can SO fix this, prevent any URL (live or not) that might trip AVG's sensors, now or in the future?

Comment: I couldn't even load the page. It was impossible to me to tell if it was a SO direct issue or AVG problem. I just wanted someone with access to take a look into it

Comment: Loads fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than any jargon, I'd guess it's upset because of the mentions of
`http://SOME-BAD-GUYS-IN-RUSSIA.COM/EXPLOIT.PHP`
(<strike>Maybe you'll get the warning here now too!</strike>  Yep.  Defanged.)

The question is about some obfuscated javascript that loads bad stuff from the above address.  Though the address isn't actually linked, I've known AV software to not be too picky about whether potential bad stuff looks clickable/active, but just warn based on signature matches.

Whether or not this is really a false positive depends on your point of view.  On the one hand, the SO page is definitely not a source of malware, but it certainly does contain a link to an exploit site, albeit a fairly neutered one.

Comment: thanks, now I am in my mobile :(

Comment: Sometimes experiments are the best way to solve a problem. :)